# Display result in dropdown and select to perform query in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I have a database named Data which has a table in which their are different names of products their id and prices, i want to make a web page using php so that i can edit,add and save the items from the web page to the DB and search the names accordingly.

```
  <html>
  <head>
 <title>Products store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p  style="font-size:20px" align="center"> <b>Product Database Editor</b> </p>
  <p>
  <form method="post">
   Enter Product Name: <input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" size="70">
 <input type="submit">
  </p>
 <form method="post">
<select id="opt" name="opt">
   <?php
$pname = $_REQUEST['pname'];

// $pname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pname']);

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
    {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
     mysql_select_db("Dataentry", $con);

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where name like '%$pname%'");
      $result_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

      if($pname==NULL)
        {
        echo "Please enter a product name!";
          }
      else if($result_rows==0)
        {
      echo "Product Name does not exist!";
        }
     else
        {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {

     $name = $row['name'];

     echo "<option value='$name_selected'>$name</option>";

   //echo ("<option value = '" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['id'] . "</option>");

      echo $name_selected;  


 echo "<br />";
 }
 }
 mysql_close($con);


  ?>
 </select>
  </form>

  </body>
   </html>
```

when i run this code i get the names list in the dropdown but after i select any name, nothing happens, how should i modify my code so that i can select any name from the dropdown and then be able to fetch the price of that particular name to edit it.
please help, coding will be much helpful.

Comment: Your forms have no action attribute. This would normally be the page to send the form results to and do something with the data sent.

Comment: Actually, if action is not present, it will just self submit the form right?

Comment: I am a PHP newbie but, if memory serves me well ` if($pname==NULL)` NULL does not mean zero, it just meaning a value of `nothing` is placed. Or I could be wrong

Comment: Do not use mysql_* it is depricated. Use PDO. And you code is SQL injection valnurable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a question like this in your dropdown menu.

`Q - How many colors does the US flag has?`

Now, from what I understand you want your choice from the drop down menu to appear instantly..

Well, here is a simple select form.

```
<form method="post">
<select id="opt" name="opt">
    <option value="four">four</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
     <option value="two">two</option>
     <option value="million">million</option>
</select>​
```

And, the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#opt").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

Now, click her a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qzYuL/) with jsFiddle to show you, how it works. 
You can copy/paste the codes and include them in your site, this is a simple code, but you if you small knowledge of Javascript you can manipulate the data the way you need it to appear. .

Comment: I am trying to do it but, nothing gets selected,'<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#opt").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});​
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<select id="opt" name="opt">
    <option value="four">four</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
     <option value="two">two</option>
     <option value="million">million</option>
</select>​ 
</form>


</body>
</html>'

Comment: I have around 1000 names in my database so i have to write it in a loop or something? .. any codes for that ?

Comment: .. working now i just have to do little change from my previous code... did this <script>
function favBrowser()
{
var mylist=document.getElementById("opt");
document.getElementById("favorite").value=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script><form method="post">
<select id="opt" onchange="favBrowser()"> ... php code ..$name = $row['name'];

 echo "<option>$name</option>";
...?> </select>
<p>Your selected name is: <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20"></p>
</form>

Comment: @user1877823 I am glad it worked out for you. I forgot to mention that, you should include Jquery in-order to use the script.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value of an input (this case, from a dropdown) `on the fly`, you need to use client-side scripting language `javascript` (or jquery) and use `ajax` to sent it to server-side, where the code is in PHP.